# Ubuntu 17.10, Xorg 1.19, amd drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics

I have hybrid graphics on my laptop. **How can I install AMD drivers for Radeon HD 6400M/7400M card on my Ubuntu 17.10** ??

The installed version of xorg is 1.19 & is not supported by the driver installer and prompts me to downgrade to version 1.10 or 6.9.

I don't know how to do it and couldn't find any help on-line.

***Please help, as I'm relatively new to Ubuntu.***

`*-display

       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff`   enter code here

In the output of **lspci** :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

Comment: Are you certain that you need to? Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C display` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek, did that!

Comment: I'm only seeing an Intel controller in your output. Have you not yet installed the Radeon HD 6400M/7400M card?

Comment: @ElderGeek, Its there. The amd drivers show up when I run 'lspci' command.